# pythonで複数のjsonファイルを読み込む方法

Tags: python, python3, json

pythonでjsonファイルを読み込みたいのですが、複数のファイルを読み込む方法がわかりません。

読み込みたいファイルが
`right_000000000000_keypoints.json`から
`right_000000000100_keypoints.json`まであるとしたら、
どのようにプログラムを組めばよろしいでしょうか。

for文と`str()`を使うというのを聞いたことがあるのですが、上手くいきません。
一応自分なりに考えたプログラムを貼っておきます。

```
import json

i = 000000000000

for i in range(100):
    # ファイルを開く
    str_count=str(i)
    json_file = open("right_" + str_count + "_keypoints.json")

    # JSONとして読み込む
    json_obj  = json.load(json_file)

    #　表示
    print(json_obj)
```

行き詰っているのでご教授お願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

str_count=str(i)に対してrjust()またはzfill()を適用しましょう。

```
str_count=str(i).rjust(12,'0')
```

または

```
str_count=str(i).zfill(12)
```

最初の引数は適用後の桁数、rjustの第二引数は付加する文字です。

その他に、今の`for ... range`だと100が範囲に入りません。101にしましょう。

```
for i in range(101):
```

さらに、ファイルが無かった場合とか、読み込みでエラーが発生した場合の検出と対処が必要です。
try except とか、with 等のキーワードで検索して対処してください。

最後に、open したファイルは for ループの中で close しましょう。

Comment: +1。ファイルの open については、`with open(ファイル名) as f:` を使うと例外や close を深く考えなくて済むのでラクです。 https://docs.python.jp/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Answer (score 1):

- `"".format()`を使う

  - 分かりやすくなる
- `with` syntaxを使う

  - [@nekketsuuu♦](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/19110/nekketsuuu) 氏の指摘の通り、ファイルオープンをブロック化することで`close`などの考慮を楽に出来る

という点を踏まえて、以下のようにやると良さそうです。

```
for file_name in ["right_{:012d}_keypoints.json".format(i) for i in range(101)]:
    with open(file_name) as f:
        # ...
```

Comment: お２人ともありがとうございます！なんとかうまく動かせたのですが、
print(read_data['people'][0]['face_keypoints_2d'])　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　このようにwithを使って出力するときにキーポイントを指定しても　　　　TypeError: string indices must be integersとエラーが出てしまいます。　　　withを使うときのキーポイントの指定方法についても教えていただけませんか？

Comment: @yoshiki さん、[別の質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/51774)にて上記エラーの追加回答をしました。 @PicoSushi さんはどちらの質問もご覧になっているので文脈が分かりますが、第三者がこの質問にない`print(read_data['people'][0]['face_keypoints_2d'])`を見ても原因を把握するのは困難です。別のエラーが出た時は、質問を新規投稿することをお勧めします。