# jsonファイルの中身の指定

Tags: python, python3, json

jsonファイルの中身が、

```
{
  "version": 1.2,
  "people": [
    {
      "pose_keypoints_2d": [
        570.599,
        272.875,
        ...,
        292.453,
        0.616146
      ],
      "face_keypoints_2d": [
        416.352,
        227.967,
        ...,
        213.009,
        0.822855
      ],
      "hand_left_keypoints_2d": [],
      "hand_right_keypoints_2d": [],
      "pose_keypoints_3d": [],
      "face_keypoints_3d": [],
      "hand_left_keypoints_3d": [],
      "hand_right_keypoints_3d": []
    }
  ]
}
```

このような中身の時にface_keypoints_2d"を指定したいのですが、エラーになってしまいます。
おそらく原因は一番最初の[と一番最後の]だとおもい、その部分を削除したら上手く読み込めました。
なんとかこの部分を削除しないで中身を指定する方法はないでしょうか。

Comment: `一番最初の[と一番最後の]` とは、 `"people"` の値のことを指していますか？

Answer (score 1):

エラーが `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str` であれば、
一番最初の[と一番最後の]で"people"の中身が配列になっているのに、配列としてアクセスしていないことが原因と予想されます。

下記のサンプルコードでjsonを書き換えずに"face_keypoints_2d"を取得できます。
サンプルコードのprint文では`j["people"][0]["face_keypoints_2d"]`と記述して、"people"配列の先頭にアクセスしています。

```
import json
# jsonの不要な項目は省略しています
s = '''{"version":1.2,"people":[{"pose_keypoints_2d":[570.599,272.875,0.719388,0.616146],
"face_keypoints_2d":[416.352,227.967,0.822855],
"hand_right_keypoints_3d":[]}]}'''
j = json.loads(s)
print(j["people"][0]["face_keypoints_2d"])
# [416.352, ...] が出力される
```

---

**コメントでの追加質問について**

ファイル読み込み時には[類似質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/51764)の回答を参考にして`json.loads`を`json.load`に読み替えてください。
`json.loads`は*json文字列*を、`json.load`は*ファイルパス*をそれぞれ引数として受け取ります。

`read_data = f.read()`として`read`を使うと`read_data`には文字列(string)型が入ります。
json型でなくstring型に対して`read_data['people']`の記述をすると下記の例外が発生します。

> TypeError: string indices must be integers

ファイル読込時のサンプルコード:

```
import json
with open("test.json", "r") as f:
    j = json.load(f)
    print(j['people'][0]['face_keypoints_2d'])
```

エラーを再現できるコードや具体的なエラーの内容を記述していただくと的確な回答を得やすいと思います。

コメントで質問を追加すると、質問がページ内に散在する上にコードのインデントも崩れて読みにくくなります。
そしてコメントを受けた回答者以外は回答しにくい状況にもなりますので、追加質問は**質問文を編集**するか別の質問として**新規投稿**することをお勧めします。

Comment: ありがとうございます！なんとかうまく動かせたのですが、
import json
with open("rightleft_000000000000_keypoints.json") as f:
    read_data = f.read()　　print(read_data['people'][0]['face_keypoints_2d'])　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　このようにwithを使って出力するときにキーポイントを指定しても　　　　TypeError: string indices must be integersとエラーが出てしまいます。　　　withを使うときのキーポイントの指定方法についても教えていただけませんか？

Comment: @yoshikiさん、コメント欄では多くの編集機能が効かないので、別途質問を立てた方が良いでしょう。上記に限って言えば、withの問題では無く、ファイル読み取りをf.read()で行っているためでしょう。json.load(f)に変えてみてください。

Comment: @kunif さん、フォローありがとうございます。コメントに気付く前に回答を更新していました。

Comment: @yoshiki さん、同一の追加質問を複数の回答者にコメントされた件については急いで解決したい気持ちからの行動とお察ししますが、こういった行為な不誠実だと受け取られる可能性があります。回答者も有志の人間である点にご配慮いただきたく存じます。